# How to reverse a filter in a pivot table excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have some difficulties with Excel, I have a pivot table and a filter on one of the columns. This filters is not a simple rule, you can say that data are chosen randomly. So, I want to be able to reverse that filter. Any solution will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Without further information this will be a rather cumbersome task in 3 steps: (1) Populate an array with all available options. (2) Eliminate from this array all the options which are currently selected in the filter. (3) Change the filter to use the newly generated array. Yet, this might not be what you want. If you are filtering on numbers you might have a filter like `< 10` or something. Or a date filter between two dates. In these cases the above solution wouldn't be optimal (to say the least).

Comment: Unfortunately, I am filtering on strings. "Change the filter to use the newly generated array" how to do that (automatically)?

Comment: You can assign the pivot filter directly the array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31416084/optimize-excel-pivot-table-filter-using-array-vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue so what I did was I selected the items I needed (filtered them) and put them in rows panel. Then I created a group for all of them - named it, lets say "Okay List". Then I removed the filter - ie, kept 'Okay list' and all the other items. Then again, made a group of all 'other items'. 
Now, I have two groups, one is "Okay List" and another "Other list". You can put them back in filters and select which ever is needed.

Hope that helps.