# Filter Pivot Table Based On User Input (Multiple Choice)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to filter a pivot table depending on the input users select.

I have a set of data ordered by month (within one year only) and I want the user to select from a multiple choice option the months they want to see data for and then action this on the pivot table.

I know how to build the multiple choice menu but couldn't find a way to automate the filtering of the pivot table. I guess I would need to store the user input into a variable and then filter the pivot table with the months included within that variable.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using the Slicer Option. It is found in Pivote table tools - Insert Slicer.

U can use the slicer on any field (its sort of like a tidy filtering tool)

Comment: I'm trying to do something different. I don't want users to touch the pivot but ask them which months they want to get the data for (via multiple option) so that I can then run my macro which is also linked to several other commands. So I need a way to filter the pivot in VBA depending on the user input - slicer won't do the job in this case :(

Comment: What have you tried so far? Break it down into sections 1)Work out how to get a list what needs to be filtered.2) When you have the list work out how to only show this list in the pivot table. Similar post found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31416084/optimize-excel-pivot-table-filter-using-array-vba